# How to use embedded c within Shoes? (ruby-serialport)

Tags: c, ruby, shoes, embedded-language

Is it possible to use something like:

```
require 'serialport.o'
```

with Shoes?  serialport.o is compiled c code as a ruby extension.

When I attempt to run the following code in shoes, I see no visible output to the screen and shoes crashes on OS X.

Thank you

CODE:

```
require "serialport.o"

port = "/dev/tty.usbserial-A1001O0o"

sp = SerialPort.new( port, 9600, 8, 1, SerialPort::NONE)

Shoes.app :width => 300, :height => 150, :margin => 10 do
  button "On" do
  sp.write( "1" )
  end
end

sp.close
```

Comment: As a side note, it's generally better to just say `require "serialport"`.  Ruby will figure out the extension for you.  That makes your code a little more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably already checked this, but does the same thing work if you aren't using Shoes? For example:

```
require "serialport.o"

port = "/dev/tty.usbserial-A1001O0o"
sp = SerialPort.new( port, 9600, 8, 1, SerialPort::NONE)
sp.write( "1" )
sp.close
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but it's with winxp.

Could you try like this?

```
Kernel::require "serialport.o"
```